# Using a variable in a library name when trying to use a library perl

Tags: perl

I want my library name to change (I have reasons), but when I use a variable in the library path, it can't seem to find it.....Can't locate APOE.pm in @INC

```
my ($plugin_name) = @ARGV; 
use lib("/usr/share/perl/5.10.1/$plugin_name");
use APOE qw(callAPOE);
```

Is this not possible?

Edit:
$plugin_name = "AIB-TorrentPanel-v2.00";
AND module name is 
APOE.pm

Comment: Have you tried `use lib("$plugin_name");`?

Comment: Yes and I checked the path.

Comment: How about using `APOE` instead of `APOE.pm`? I'm assuming `APOE.pm` is in a subdirectory of `/usr/share/perl/5.10.1/` called `APOE`. If it isn't, try putting it in a subdir.

Comment: Do you mean to rename the file with no pm extension? I'm not sure what you mean. ohhh. No the subdirectory is called AIB-TorrentPanel-v2.00

Comment: No. If `APOE.pm` is directly under `/usr/share/perl/5.10.1/` then try putting it in a subdirectory called `/usr/share/perl/5.10.1/APOE`. And call your script with just `APOE`.

Comment: I don't believe the names need to match. I've created plenty of libraries, but I've never made a path to one using a variable. Which is what it doesn't like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply write:

```
use lib "/usr/share/perl/5.10.1/$ARGV[0]";
```

or, if you need to do something more complicated to set up the directory name than your example code shows:

```
my $plugin_name;
BEGIN {
    ($plugin_name) = @ARGV;
}
use lib "/usr/share/perl/5.10.1/$plugin_name";
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `my ($plugin_name) = @ARGV;` will run at run-time, it is too late for `lib`. According to [the manual of `lib`](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html), `use lib LIST;` is almost equals

```
BEGIN { unshift(@INC, LIST) }
```

but your `$plugin_name` would not be available at that time.

However, you could replace your `use` with a `require`, like this:

```
my ($plugin_name) = @ARGV;
require "/usr/share/perl/5.10.1/$plugin_name/APOE.pm";
```